# Displaying current Facebook notifications

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm trying to display a user's Facebook notifications on a web page much like how it's displayed in Facebook itself. However, I'm stuck on how exactly I can make this query to the Facebook API and then update the web page.

I've created a query that should hopefully return what I need:

```
SELECT notification_id, sender_id, title_html, body_html, href
FROM notification
WHERE recipient_id=<uid>
AND is_unread = 1
AND is_hidden = 0
```

The thing I'm stuck on and can't really find anything about how I can send this query using JavaScript? Do I have to make an AJAX request to a separate PHP page that returns the response or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
FB.api({
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT notification_id, sender_id, title_html, body_html, href'
        + ' FROM notification'
        + ' WHERE recipient_id=' + uid
        + ' AND is_unread = 1'
        + ' AND is_hidden = 0'
}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```